# webgl / Three.js - subtracting volumes

Tags: three.js

Using webgl and three.js, how can one subtract a volume from a geometry?

Lets say I want to let the user describe a wall by specifying its height/width/length. I plug their input into a BoxGeometry.

`let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(h, w,l);`

Now I want to let them to specify a window within that wall. I take the windows position in the wall and its dimensions as input.

Is it now possible to subtract that volume (SubVolume) from the previously specified box using three.js?

If not, what is the right approach for doing this?

Comment: `three.js` does not provide an API for this but there are third-party CSG libraries that might be useful in this context.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I played around a bit with [THREE-CSGMesh](https://github.com/manthrax/THREE-CSGMesh). Seems it can work, so I might revisit it later. Also getting some artifacts but that could be me doing something wrong.For now I might rethink my approach as building a model with input

Comment: ...from the user seems more complex than I expected. Perhaps I'll look into some 2d libraries first and see if that will suffice for my purposes.